# Can I use sshpass in Windows?

Tags: sshpass

I am trying to ssh to Linux without entering a password from Windows system.
I have downloaded sshpass-1.08 and compiled it successfully.
But when I tried to ssh to Linux with sshpass, I still had to enter a password.